# upstart, exec and stderr

Tags: upstart, error-handling

I am using `syslog-ng` on a Ubuntu Lucid machine with the following `upstart` script:

```
# syslog-ng - system logging daemon
#

description     "Syslog-ng daemon"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
stop on runlevel [!2345]

expect fork
respawn

pre-start script
    test -x /usr/sbin/syslog-ng || { stop; exit 0; }
    mkdir -p -m0755 /var/run/syslog-ng
end script

exec /usr/sbin/syslog-ng -p /var/run/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.pid
```

When the `syslog-ng` configuration file is wrong, `syslog-ng` outputs an error message on stderr. Unfortunately, this error is caught by upstart and doesn't get to the console when starting the service, so there is no way to know why the service start failed.

Is it normal that upstart would catch stderr? Can it be set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is documented in [`init(5)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man5/init.5.html); you can add the following line to your `/etc/init/syslog-ng.conf` to see output:

```
console output
```

---

Alternatively, you can see output from all upstart scripts when you add the following to the kernel boot parameters:

```
INIT_VERBOSE=yes
```

You can do that temporarily by editing the parameters in the grub menu during boot, or (more) permanently by editing `/etc/default/grub` and adding it to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`, then afterwards run `update-grub`.

For more information and best practices,  see [The Upstart Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/).

Comment: Silly me, I was reading `man 1 init` and not even considering `man 5 init`. I'll try that tomorrow, it seems like the right answer :-)

Comment: I understand adding "console output" sends the console output to /dev/console, but where can I read that from? Is it logged in some file?

Answer (score 0):

If the stdout is getting through what you can do is. which will pipe the stderr to stdout which should solve your problem. :)

```
syslog-ng 2>&1
```

Comment: Nope, neither stdout nor stderr get through. Thanks for proposing though.